# Pointer Manipulation? C++

Tags: c++, pointers

Can someone please tell me what line 2 is doing here? 
I checked to see if it was just assigning the address of a to b but it isn't.

```
int a = 5, *b;
b = (int*) a;
```

Comment: b = &a; thats what you need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read some good C++ programming book about *type casts* and pointers.

So on the second line, `a` contains 5. You are casting it to a pointer (to int) with `(int*)a`. This gives some (invalid) pointer containing the address 5.

on some free standing C++ runtime environments - perhaps some cheap microcontroller - the address 5 might be meaningful and legitimate (but even that is very unlikely for 5). But usually not on hosted C++ environments (e.g. compiling on and for Linux, Windows, MacOSX, Hurd, ...)

As soon as you would dereference that pointer (e.g. with `int c= *b;`), you'll get [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), very often some [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)

You might want `b = &a;` as commented by [technusm1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4385319/technusm1)

Comment: perfect answer, type casting is what I was uncertain about. Thank you!